# how to change position of diagonal line in background using CSS and HTML?

Tags: css

What I'm trying to do is have a diagonal line in the background (positioned below the darker color of a two-color diagonal background). And I should be able to put an image in front of it. I hope this is clear, but if not, please see image of what it should look like.
[need both a diagonal line and two-color diagonal background to be the entire background, behind an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEABA.png)

The two-color diagonal background, along with the diagonal line below it should both be positioned behind an image (the flower image in this case).

And it needs to be responsive.

The CSS code I've tried is:

```
    body { 
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-70deg, #555b60 50%, white 50%);  
    }

    /* Diagonal line is needed in background */
    .line1 {
        width: 109%;
        /* max-width: 100vw; */
        height: 50vh;
        border-bottom: 7px solid grey;
        -webkit-transform:
            translateY(50px)
            translateX(-60px)
            rotate(-20deg);
        position: absolute;
        top: -10px;
        left: -70px;
    }
```

But the problem is, the line is in front of the image. And I need to have the image in front of the line.

I tried another approach, to use a linear gradient to make a line, and it does go behind the image. But then the problem there is that the two-color diagonal background is not there anymore:

```
body { 
        background: linear-gradient(-40deg, rgba(0,0,0,0) calc(50% - 5px), rgba(192,192,192,1) calc(50% - 5px), rgba(0,0,0,0) calc(50% + 5px)); 
        position: relative;
    }
```

I've tried to add both the diagonal line and the two-color diagonal background as a background separated by commas but this doesn't work.

Any suggestions to make this happen would be really appreciated.

Comment: you said the code was working but the line was above the image, did you try a `z-index` on both the image and the line?

Comment: Just tried z-index and that didn't work. But, found that by using 'position relative' on the image seemed to do the trick. Still not quite how we want it but will keep at it. Thanks for the tip with z-index though! working on that got me to try position relative which put the image on top of the line!

Comment: Ramon de Vries, thank you. Your idea about z-index is what led to my repositioning in a different way and got it working how we needed! If you add as answer, I can upvote it!

Comment: my suggestion is not worth an answer. but i am happy to hear you got it all working. happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is interested, the solution I came up with below will give a diagonal two-color background with a line below it at the same angle. The first linear gradient makes a diagonal line. The rotation can be changed with degree angle. The vertical position can be changed with the calc(%). The second linear gradient makes diagonal two color background and the angle can be changed with the degree rotation.

```
body { 
        background: 
        linear-gradient(-20deg, transparent calc(45% - 4px), rgba(0,0,0,1) calc(45% - 4px), rgba(0,0,0,1) calc(45% + 4px), transparent calc(45% + 4px)),
        linear-gradient(-20deg, white 50%, black 50%); 
    }
```